# vkMapMemory, returns an "Access is denied." error

Tags: c++, vulkan

I've been working on a Vulkan based graphical engine, and whilst trying to create a buffer,
I have encountered an issue with the `vkMapMemory()` function. In the code shown below,
the program returns an ["Access is denied" (-1073741819 or C0000005)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) error. Error happends inside the `vkMapMemory()` call, and I can't check its returned `VkResult`.

```
    void createVertexBuffer(size_t sizeOfBuffer, void * _vertices , VkBuffer * _vertexBuffer, VkDeviceMemory * _vertexBufferMemory)
    {
        VkDeviceSize bufferSize = sizeOfBuffer;
    
        VkBuffer stagingBuffer;
        VkDeviceMemory stagingBufferMemory;
        createBuffer(bufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, &stagingBuffer, &stagingBufferMemory);
    
        void* data;
        if(vkMapMemory(_device, *_vertexBufferMemory, 0, bufferSize, 0, &data) != VK_SUCCESS)
            printf("This is not printed");
        memcpy(data, _vertices, sizeOfBuffer);
        vkUnmapMemory(_device, *_vertexBufferMemory);
    
        createBuffer(bufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT, _vertexBuffer, _vertexBufferMemory);
    
        copyBuffer(stagingBuffer, *_vertexBuffer, bufferSize);
    
        vkDestroyBuffer(_device, stagingBuffer, NULL);
        vkFreeMemory(_device, stagingBufferMemory, NULL);
    
        return;
    }
```

For some additional information:

- `sizeOfBuffer` in this case is equal to `96`
- The `_vertices` array size is indeed also equal to `96`, given that it looks like this:

```
   _vertices[0][0] -1.000000 0.000000
   _vertices[0][1] -1.000000 0.000000
   _vertices[0][2] 0.000000 0.000000
   _vertices[1][0] 1.000000 0.000000
   _vertices[1][1] -1.000000 0.000000
   _vertices[1][2] 0.000000 0.000000
   _vertices[2][0] 1.000000 0.000000
   _vertices[2][1] 1.000000 0.000000
   _vertices[2][2] 0.000000 0.000000
   _vertices[3][0] -1.000000 0.000000
   _vertices[3][1] 1.000000 0.000000
   _vertices[3][2] 0.000000 0.000000
```

- The size of three lines is equal to 24 because `(sizeof(glm::vec3)=12)` and three lines contain two `glm::vec3` structs:

```
    typedef struct MKTAGA2 {
        glm::vec3 position;
        glm::vec3 color;
    } MKTAGA;
```

Comment: What is `_vertexBufferMemory` set to? Please show a [mre]

Comment: Thank you for the comment, because that was the issue.
I was using the ```_vertexBufferMemory``` when working on ```stagingBufferMemory```.
After replacing it with the

```C
    void* data;
    VK_CHECK(vkMapMemory(_device, stagingBufferMemory, 0, bufferSize, 0, &data));
    memcpy(data, _vertices, sizeOfBuffer);
    vkUnmapMemory(_device, stagingBufferMemory);
```

everything was fine.

Comment: are you sure `_device` and `_vertexBufferMemory` are initialized properly? In my experience 0xC0000005 errors result from trying to do things with null/invalid pointers

Answer (score 0):

I was mapping the `_vertexBufferMemory` when I should've been mapping the `stagingBufferMemory`
here is the fixed code:

```
    void createVertexBuffer(size_t sizeOfBuffer, void * _vertices , VkBuffer * _vertexBuffer, VkDeviceMemory * _vertexBufferMemory)
    {
        VkDeviceSize bufferSize = sizeOfBuffer;
    
        VkBuffer stagingBuffer;
        VkDeviceMemory stagingBufferMemory;
        createBuffer(bufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, &stagingBuffer, &stagingBufferMemory);
    
        void* data;
        vkMapMemory(_device, stagingBufferMemory, 0, bufferSize, 0, &data);
        memcpy(data, _vertices, sizeOfBuffer);
        vkUnmapMemory(_device, stagingBufferMemory);

        createBuffer(bufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT, _vertexBuffer, _vertexBufferMemory);
    
        copyBuffer(stagingBuffer, *_vertexBuffer, bufferSize);
    
        vkDestroyBuffer(_device, stagingBuffer, NULL);
        vkFreeMemory(_device, stagingBufferMemory, NULL);
    
        return;
    }
```